# Prisma Client not initialising when Nextjs project is being deployed to Caprover

Tags: next.js, prisma, caprover

When trying to deploy my Nextjs v12 projects to my Caprover server I am now seeing an unexpected error related to prisma:

> Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma
> generate" and try to import it again.

Does anybody know how I can go about trying to identify what may be causing this issue?

P.S. The project builds fine when being built locally with `npm run build` & the project has previously been deployed without issue. I have also tried running `npx prisma generate` and deploying again.

P.P.S When adding `RUN npx prisma generate` to my Dockerfile, a new error is returned:

```
Error: Get config: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by changing the Node version in my Dockerfile as suggested in this thread https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14073. Really weird for this issue to seemingly come out of nowhere but it's working ‍♂️